# How to convert html `abbr` tag text to a text in parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, abbr

I need to convert hundreds of html sentences generated by an outside source to readable text, and I have a question about conversion of `abbr` tag. Below is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = "<abbr title=\"World Health Organization\" style=\"color:blue\">WHO</abbr> is a specialized agency of the <abbr title=\"United Nations\" style=\"color:#CCCC00\">UN</abbr>."
print (BeautifulSoup(text).get_text())
```

This code returns *"WHO is a specialized agency of the UN."*. However, what I want is *"WHO (World Health Organization) is a specialized agency of the UN (United Nations)."* Is there a way to do this? Maybe another module rather than BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements in `soup.contents`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
text = "<abbr title=\"World Health Organization\" style=\"color:blue\">WHO</abbr> is a specialized agency of the <abbr title=\"United Nations\" style=\"color:#CCCC00\">UN</abbr>."
d = ''.join(str(i) if i.name is None else f'{i.text} ({i["title"]})' for i in soup(text, 'html.parser').contents)
```

Output:

```
'WHO (World Health Organization) is a specialized agency of the UN (United Nations).'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, with one of the worst algorithms in the history of algorithms:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = "<abbr title=\"World Health Organization\" style=\"color:blue\">WHO</abbr> is a specialized agency of the <abbr title=\"United Nations\" style=\"color:#CCCC00\">UN</abbr>."
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
inside_abbrs = soup.find_all('abbr')

string_out = ''

for i in inside_abbrs: 
  s = BeautifulSoup(str(i), 'html.parser')
  t = s.find('abbr').attrs['title']
  split_soup = re.findall(r"[\w]+|[.,!?;]", soup.text)
  bind_caps = ''.join(re.findall(r'[A-Z]', t))

  for word in split_soup:
    if word == bind_caps:
      string_out += word + " (" + t + ") " 
      break
    else:
      string_out += word + " "

string_out = string_out.strip()
string_out += '.'
print(string_out)
```

#### Output

```
WHO (World Health Organization) WHO is a specialized agency of the UN (United Nations).
```